# Expectation of the trace of random matrix with an inverse insided

Tags: random-matrices, expectation

Consider a $N$-dimensional random complex vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb C^{N \times 1}$ following the complex Gaussian distribution, i.e., $\mathbf{x} \sim {CN}(0,\sigma^2 \mathbf{I})$, where $\mathbf{I}$ is the $N \times N$ identity matrix and ${CN}$ denotes the complex Gaussian distribution.

I want to calculate the expected value of the following formula, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left( {\rm trace} \left( \mathbf{A}^H ( \mathbf{Bx}\mathbf{x}^H \mathbf{B}^H+ \mathbf{I}   )^{-1} \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^H \right) \right)
\end{align}
where both $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are deterministic $M \times N$ complex matrices, $\mathbf{A}^H$ denote the conjugate transpose of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$, and $(\cdot)^{-1}$ denotes the matrix inverse.
I'm new to this area. Could anyone give a hint or a textbook? Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi Prokins -- as this question stands, you have enough undefined terms in your post to make me wonder if this is AI generated; apologies in advance if this is just my ignorance, but could you define the various variables you've sprinkled throughout your post?

Comment: Hi, Alec, sorry for the confusion. I have edited the problem and hope I have made it clear. Thanks for your comment!